MAE and RMSE by groups
Consider five real numbers $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$, $B_1$, $B_2$. They are errors, the five differences between real values and estimated values. The MAE(mean absolute error) is
$$\text{MAE} = \frac{|A_1|+|A_2|+|B_1|+|B_2|+|B_3|}5$$
and the RMSE(root mean squared error) is
$$\text{RMSE} = \sqrt{\frac{{A_1}^2+{A_2}^2+{B_1}^2+{B_2}^2+{B_3}^2}5}.$$
Grouping these numbers by $\{A_1,A_2\}$ and $\{B_1,B_2,B_3\}$, we have two sums $A_1+A_2$ and $B_1+B_2+B_3$. We can think of MAE and RMSE of these grouped sums ;
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{MAE}_{\text{group}}&=\frac{|A_1+A_2|+|B_1+B_2+B_3|}2\\
\text{RMSE}_{\text{group}}&=\sqrt{\frac{(A_1+A_2)^2+(B_1+B_2+B_3)^2}2}
\end{align*}
$$
Is there any general inequalities that hold? ;e.g. $\text{MAE}\ge\text{MAE}_{\text{group}}$, $\text{MAE}\le\text{MAE}_{\text{group}}$, $\text{RMSE}\ge\text{RMSE}_{\text{group}}$, $\text{RMSE}\le\text{RMSE}_{\text{group}}$. I illustrated the most simple nontrivial case, but the number of groups and the numbers of elements in groups can be bigger.
In my example, grouped ones are smaller : $\text{MAE}\ge\text{MAE}_{\text{group}}$ and $\text{RMSE}\ge\text{RMSE}_{\text{group}}$. But is it true in general?

when you say "They are errors", do you mean that $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},B_{1},B_{2}\geq 0$ and that these five numbers are all real-valued?

@DennisMarx $A_i$ and $B_i$ are real and they can be either positive, zero or negative. Let $a_1$, $a_2$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$ be an estimated values, which is the result of a scientific experiment. And let $\bar a_1$, $\bar a_2$, $\bar b_1$, $\bar b_2$, $\bar b_3$. All the $a_i$, $b_i$, $\bar a_i$ and $\bar b_i$ are real values. Then the errors are $A_1=a_1-\bar a_1$, $A_2=a_2-\bar a_2$, $B_1=b_1-\bar b_1$, $B_2=b_2-\bar b_2$, $B_3=b_3-\bar b_3$.

@Doug You're right. Thanks for correcting an error. I though there might be any inequality since there are thousands of inequalities in mathematics ; Jensen, Minkowski, Cauchy-Schwarz etc. I hoped to prove one of the two directions. I am to experiment with python as you did.
